# Using foreignObject with D3 transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

In a project I'm working on, I'm chaining a series of D3 transitions on `exit`. Essentially, when elements are removed from the data set, they are to be 'focused' in a sense that their data is highlighted and more SVG elements are appended relevant to the element that's exiting.

Everything looks great when the transitions happen on the same page – nothing breaks, only one thing shows up at once, and all is good.

However, when I leave the tab for an extended period of time (such that multiple items would have been exited by the time I return), what happens is that everything is cleared *except* the `span` elements inside the `foreignObject` elements that had been exited in the time I was on a different tab/out of focus. They stay on the page until the the next element to be exited goes through all of its transitions (probably because `selectAll('foreignObject.textBox')`).

Here's how I'm approaching the problem:

```
svg.exit()
  .each(function(d, i) {

    ...

    textBox = container.selectAll('foreignObject.textBox')
      .data([root]).enter()
      .append('foreignObject')
      .attr({
        class: 'textBox',
        x: root.getX() - 30 * (flippedX ? -1 : 1) + 45,
        y: root.getY() - 30 * (flippedY ? -1 : 1) - 25,
        width: 0,
        height: 55
      })
      .html('<div class="graph-msg"><span class="graph-msg-text">' + message.body + '</span>');

    textBox.transition()
      .delay(TR_MOVE_TO_CENTER)
      .duration(TR_EXPAND)
      .attr({
        width: 180
      })
      .each('end', function(node, i) {
        textBox.transition()
          .delay(TR_SHOW)
          .each('end', function(node, i) {
            fadeOut(textBox, TR_FADE);
          });
      });
```

The fadeOut function is shown here:

```
function fadeOut(d3Elem, millis, onEnd) {
  d3Elem.transition()
    .duration(millis)
    .style({ opacity: 0 })
    .each('end', onEnd || function(d, i) {
      d3Elem.remove();
    });
}
```

Any ideas about how to fix this? I need to use `foreignObject` because I need text to wrap around. Is this just a part of using `foreignObject`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) says that a `foreignObject`'s contents are drawn by a different user agent – could that have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Is this specific to `foreignObject` or is it the case in general that elements aren't removed when you're not looking?

Comment: Specific to `foreignObject`, I think. I have a lot of other elements that I'm appending in a very similar fashion and all of those do not appear when I come back to the page after being on some other tab or out of focus for a long time, it's only the HTML inside of the `foreignObject` that's staying around.

Comment: @Dennis Just a couple of quick thoughts. First, `foreignObject` is not supported in IE. Second, depending on your situation (I did not look too closely), [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1642) may help. The linked issue is exemplified in this [gist](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).